# Mysql database connection php in Twilio

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

How do i connect my database to pull data from database and according to that data need to send messages in twilio ?

Comment: mysql connection is ok i want to know how to connect it with TWILIO

Comment: Follow twilio documentation.

Comment: what does Twilio documentation state?

Comment: in twilio documentation it doesn't show to connect to database through php

Comment: In twillio you can only do is generate the request to their APIs

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047394/how-can-i-connect-my-database-to-twilio